# Drawing image onto canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw an image onto canvas. The image is within the folder as of html file. But when i call the drawImage() function, the image doesn't draw. Here is my code,

```
var upcan = document.createElement("canvas");
upcan.width = "190";
upcan.height = "380";
upcan.style.cssText = 'border-radius:25px; '
var upctx = upcan.getContext('2d');

var pb = new Image();

pb.onload = function() {
upctx.drawImage(pb,0,0,100,400);
};
pb.src = "photobooth.png";
var canvasData = upcan.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: [Works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/eF8HN/).  Did you check your dev tools to make sure `photobooth.png` is being found?

Comment: Yes it's perfectly fine!

Comment: The matter is when i do upcan.toDataURL("image/png"); It doesn't get the correct data! It omits everything that has been done in pb.onload!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in upcan.toDataURL("image/png");. It doesn't draw an image that is sourced from outside, due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code... you have provided src after draw image so it is now drawing..

```
var upcan = document.createElement("canvas");
    upcan.width = "190";
    upcan.height = "380";
    upcan.style.cssText = 'border-radius:25px; '
    var upctx = upcan.getContext('2d');

    var pb = new Image();
    pb.src = "~/../urpath/photobooth.png"; //give here proper path
    pb.onload = function() {
    upctx.drawImage(pb,0,0,100,400);

    };
```

I think it will solve ur problem

Comment: that's not the problem. If you visit sites for canvas tutorials, everywhere src is after draw image!

Comment: `onload` is called asynchronously.  You need to set it *before* the `src` property to make sure there is something to call when the file loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var upcan;
    var img = d.createElement('img');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg, aName) { 
       return function(e) {
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
        aImg.onload = function(){
            var upcan = createImgCanvas(aImg, 100, 400);
        }
    }; })(img, file.name);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

function createImgCanvas(img, imgWidth, imgHeight) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = imgWidth;
    canvas.height = imgHeight;
    var imageCanvas2D = canvas.getContext("2d");
    try{
        imageCanvas2D.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    } catch(err) { alert(err);}
    return canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var upcan = document.createElement("canvas");
upcan.width = "190";
upcan.height = "380";
upcan.style.cssText = 'border-radius:25px; '
var upctx = upcan.getContext('2d');

var pb = new Image();
pb.src = "photobooth.png";
pb.onload = function() {
upctx.drawImage(pb,0,0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you append the canvas to the document or any other element?

Comment: I don't need to append it. I am saving it as image after drawing. I also draw some other canvases onto this one and that works fine but image drawing is not working!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in Chrome, right on this page with the developer tools, using one of the existing images in this page and appending the canvas to the body. The code works very well, the problem must be in some other place.

Comment: The problem is when i do canvas.toDataUrl("image/png"); it doesn't take it fully!

Answer (score 0):

The load handler is run asynchronously; it won't execute until after the image has been downloaded.  The current script will continue executing so the snapshot of the canvas will be taken before the image downloads.  Move your processing into the load handler to make sure everything has been drawn before capturing it.

```
pb.onload = function() {
    upctx.drawImage(pb,0,0,100,400);
    var canvasData = upcan.toDataURL("image/png");
    // do stuff
};
pb.src = "photobooth.png";
```